# Why are my Tkinter column widths misaligned?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I made an Excel-like grid for entering data that will be exported to another program. The top row is "frozen" so that it remains visible when you scroll down. I'm using a list `ColWidths = [15, 15, 40]` to define the widths of the widgets in the top row, and the widgets in the scroll-able rows beneath.

I read that if you don't give a unit, `width` defaults to pixels. Even so, I made sure to use the same font size in the top row and all the other rows.

Oddly the columns still appear to be slightly different widths. Any idea how to fix this?

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) CODE:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog,filedialog,colorchooser,messagebox,Frame,Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import textwrap

root = tk.Tk()

canv_1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="blue")
canv_1.pack(side="top", fill="both")#, fill="both", expand=True)

canv_2 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray")
canv_2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

frame = tk.Frame(canv_2)

# create, bind & position scrollbar
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(canv_2, orient="vertical", command=canv_2.yview)
canv_2.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

canv_2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canv_2.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canv_2=canv_2: onFrameConfigure(canv_2))

labels = ["Chapter Title", "Slide", "Instructions"]
ColWidths = [15, 15, 40]
root.label_wid = []
font1 = ("arial", 15, "bold")

load1 = Image.open("StartingImage.jpg")
root.render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)

ch_text = []

for i in range(len(labels)):
    root.label_wid.append(tk.Label(canv_1,
                                   font=font1,
                                   relief="raised",
                                   text=labels[i],
                                   width=ColWidths[i],
                                   ).grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="we"))

c1 = "#a9d08e"
c2 = "#8dd1bf"


Title_col = [
    tk.Entry(
        frame,
        bg = c1,
        width = ColWidths[0],
        font = font1)
    for y in range(0, 5)
]

Slide_col = [
    tk.Entry(
        frame,
        bg = c2,
        width = ColWidths[1],
        font = font1)
    for y in range(0, 5)
]

instruction_col = [
    tk.Text(
        frame,
        bg="white",
        wrap="word",
        font=font1, width = ColWidths[2], height=10)
    for y in range(0, 5)
]

for y in range(0, 5):
    Title_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=0, sticky='news')
    Slide_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=1, sticky='news')
    instruction_col[y].grid(row=y+1, column=2, sticky='news')

bt1 = tk.Button(canv_1, text="Export", font=font1, bg="#f5b942")
bt1.grid(row=0, column=4)
load2 = Image.open("scroll-up-gray.png")
root.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
load3 = Image.open("scroll-down.png")
root.render3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load3)

root.mainloop()
```

GUI SCREENSNIP:
[image]

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a mcve. For example, do we really need the images in order to reproduce a problem with column widths? Do we really need seven columns, or would 2-3 be sufficient?

Comment: BTW: see [PandasTable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataexplore.html#table-layout) which can display table in `tkitner` using data in `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `bold` from your font or figure out how much to add to the image column (your original screen grab) to compensate. Seriously though, just remove `bold` from your font and watch it all magically work.

`bold` is adding extra pixels to all of your labels, and it isn't adding anything in all of those empty boxes. It took me like 2 hours to figure this out (lol)! I even rewrote your entire example much better and still couldn't get it to work ... until I realized that the instruction label was being forced out of the window bounds. Some kind of way that triggered the font format in my head. I simply removed `bold` and everything worked. I then re-copy/pasted your example and removed `bold`. It still worked.

I understand that you ultimately want to keep `bold`. You will have to use line-metrics or something more reliable than simply telling every column to be the same size. The main point is, at least now you know the culprit and why.

edit:

I also got it to work by doing the below instead. Unfortunately, I can't explain why this works. Obviously, I know that we are just adding an inner padding to each cell, but I don't understand why dividing the cell width by 2 works in every case. This may even cause problems later. I simply don't know, but in this example case it seems to work almost perfect.

```
for y in range(0, 5):
    Title_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=0, sticky='news', ipadx=ColWidths[0]/2)
    Slide_col[y].grid(row=y + 1, column=1, sticky='news', ipadx=ColWidths[1]/2)
    instruction_col[y].grid(row=y+1, column=2, sticky='news', ipadx=ColWidths[2]/2)
```

edit 2:

If you want the results of the above code to appear absolutely perfect in line with the header columns, specify `highlightthickness=0` in your canvas instances. This will remove the canvas borders, which are creating a tiny offset.

```
canv_1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
canv_1.pack(side="top", fill="both")#, fill="both", expand=True)

canv_2 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray", highlightthickness=0)
canv_2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

[image: results]

Comment: do you know what the relationship is between font format and width? What is the unit for `width`? Maybe there's a better way to define width that is more reliable, such as percentage of the screen.

Comment: @Wes Tomer ~ see the addition to my answer. I got it to work without getting rid of `bold`. I'm not sure the results are exactly what you want, but it does work. Regarding your question ~ no, I don't know a better way because I do all of this completely different. I use `ttk` and a completely custom theme with custom widgets.

Comment: @Wes Tomer ~ I made one more addition to my answer which gets the columns dead-on.